# SQL join fails on temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm having trouble joining two temp tables where all columns are `varchar(MAX)`.

I'm trying to join on columns that both contains value 'SV-001', when I change value to 'SV-0' there are no problems, but when I add 1 more '0' it fails?

Values on both tables are collected from different standard tables and I have tested the results before I join them - even excel can compare values, so I'm sure values are identical.

I'm joining them like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Speedwell_setup 
JOIN #Speedwell_data ON #Speedwell_setup.Productcode = #Speedwell_data.Product1
```

All I get is a empty result, no errors or anything, I hope that you can help me out here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! And don't just use `VACHAR(MAX)` for everything just because you're too lazy to think of what size you **really need** for your column ...

Comment: I agree that I should use appropiate datatypes, however varchar(max) was a last desperate try. Been trying char, nvarchar and everyother types and before MAX I used a varchar(20) but still the same results.

Comment: When joining strings against each other, there's always the possibility of extra characters (possibly non-visible) that are in one of the two strings you compare - or one string might contain two spaces, while the other only has one - stuff like that typically causes string equality matches to fail. Can you check for that in your case?

Comment: Having `(N)VARCHAR` or `CHAR` types as key is a bad decision. Use eg `INT` types instead. Joining on `INT` types is a lot more efficient, and it would sidestep your problem.

Comment: I've just deleted both temp tables, created them again and did the same with one of the standard tables, typed in everything manually again and now it seems to be working - just don't understand why excel could compare them and find matches. That's why I was so sure they were identical